# Kafka 0.9 are log compaction delete markers immediately effective masking earlier messages?

Tags: apache-kafka

In Kafka docs, [log compaction](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Log+Compaction) says

> Compaction also allows from deletes. A message with a key and a null
>   payload will be treated as a delete from the log. This delete marker
>   will cause any prior message with that key to be removed (as would any
>   new message with that key), but delete markers are special in they
>   will themselves be cleaned out of the log after a period of time. The
>   point in time at which deletes are no longer retained is given above.

My scenario: I send messages flowing into an in-memory engine and they come out the other side out-of-order. A message can spend anywhere from zero to hours in side the engine's state machine cache (it is a rule processor engine).

Thus, I want to know if I can use log compaction as my durability answer to always know which messages are still in-memory in the engine for fault tolerance. So a replay from message offset 0 will always work to reload what was in-memory in the engine, and then pick up with streaming in whatever newer messages are present. This should work (theoretically) since every message exiting the engine has a delete marker appended for its <key>.

Is this accurate? My main concern is to verify that with log compaction enabled:

1. A delete marker is nothing more than a key> with a null value for payload. There is no other special treatment to producer.send() one.
2. The moment a delete marker is appended to a topic and committed to the same partition with the earlier "real" message, any read of the partition will skip the superceded message. It is imperative that I rely on this happening immediately and not have to wait on any cleanup phase to kick in. I assume the compaction cleaner is simply performing physical removal of what has already been logically removed from the moment the <key> was reused.

It is important for my use to verify that an older <key> message is not present for reads, from the moment a superceding <key> message got appended.